# Kubernetes not pulling latest image

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Something which is puzzling me

I have written a docker file v1 with a v1 of my code.

for example:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

I am building and pushing my image to docker hub with the tag development (leexha/sample:development) . For example a v2 of my code is as below

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello EARTH!'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

I can confirm that my latest code is being pushed into docker hub as I did a docker run and its working fine.

However, when I try to run the latest docker image in kubernetes doing a `kubectl run sample --image=leexha/sample:development` it is strangely fetching v1 of my code (Hello World)

Is there any reason why this working like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, performance. According to the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/) the default pull policy is `IfNotPresent` unless your image is using the tag `latest`. Override by setting `imagePullPolicy` to `Always`.

EDIT: you don't want to check for and pull updated images in production, where a tagged image should never change. Even the check can be costly. In development you can use `latest` or override with `imagePullPolicy`.

Answer (score 1):

You can define `imagePullPolicy: Always` in your deployment file.
For production environment do not use `latest` docker image tag.